# Bitwise Relation between Shift Operator and One's Complement

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am new to Bitwise Operator,I found the following line in wikipedia of "Bitwise operator" -(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation )

> If the binary number is treated as ones' complement, then the same
>   right-shift operation results in division by 2n and rounding toward
>   zero.

But not sure what it meant.Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Shifting a binary number one bit to the right effectively halves all the bit values. Example: decimal 10 / binary 01010 shifted one to the right is decimal 5 / binary 0101. This most-significant bit of decimal 10 is worth 8. After the shift, the most-signifiant bit of decimal 5 is worth 4. Negative numbers in one's complement representation show the same effect: All bit values are halved by shifting one to the right.

Answer (score 0):

It's about Right Shift Operation. Below answer is taken from my own blog:

[Bitwise Operations](https://javanotable.blogspot.com/2017/04/bitwise-operations.html)

`>>` is a right shift bitwise operator which works exactly like left shift operator but it’s different in 2 aspects only.

> 1. If number is negative (most significant bit is 1) , it will fill gaps with 1 otherwise with 0
> 2. It shifts bits from right

```
7 >> 2 

0000 0111 >> 2 

0000 01 (See two 1’s from right have been shifted) 

00 0000 01 (Added two 0’s, because number is positive) 

0000 0001 = 1
```

So `7 >> 2 = 1`

For negative number, it fills gaps with 1 instead of 0.

Remember `7 >> 2 = 1` and `-7 >> 2 = -1`.

It just preserves the sign, everything else remains same. If you closely observe right shift operator, you will find that it can be written as:

```
7 >> 2 => (7) / (2^2) => 7/4 => 1
```

This is what Wikipedia means, you can take right shift operator as:

NUMBER (7) / power (2, NUMBER_OF_TIMES (2)) and rounds it off